# Test class constructor in c# implementing vs. ClassInitialize

Tags: c#, unit-testing, test-class

I implement a test class for unit tests in VS2013

Inside that class I define the following struct and list:

```
private struct TestCase
   {
        public string Statement { set; get; }
        public string ExpectedStatement { set; get; }
        public MyClass[] ContainedEntities;
        public MyClass[] NonContainedEntities;
    }

private List<TestCase> m_TestCases;
```

I want to initialize the `m_TestCases` with 5 TestCase.

Ho do I do that? Implement Constructor?(once I read that implementing constructor for test class is bad idea).Use `ClassInitialize`? but it is static....

Comment: Which test framework do you use?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - VS2013,C#,UnitTest

Answer (score 1):

If the data is used in each test and could be mutable (changeable from test to test) then initialize the data in the method with `ClassInitialize` as the attribute for *it is only loaded once*.

If you want it to be loaded *before* each unit test use `TestInitialize` for it will be loaded *a new* for each test.

See

- [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.aspx) (For all attribute options)
- [ClassInitialize Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx)
- [TestInitialize Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx)

Comment: ClassInitialize is static....My member is private....Does it mean that I can`t define private members in the testclass?

Comment: Should I always introduce TestCleanup if I have TestInitialize ?

Comment: @Yakov Only if you need to reset state to an original condition due to tests which change information or need to *cleanup* say com references or what not. For example, Say one runs a test which accesses a database and writes information to tables. Using TestCleanup, one can undo what the test(s) wrote to the database, returning it to a *pristine* state.

Comment: @Yakov One can have private members, but the question is why? The test class is not consumed by any other entity/class so whether the member is private or not is moot.

Comment: @Yakov Have you found anything different?